# Import a whole dataset into one MongoDB document

Tags: mongodb, document, mongoimport

I'm trying to find a way to import a whole dataset into one MongoDB document. Every solution I've tried only inserts many documents instead of one. What I've tried so far.

mongoimport --db=dbName --collection=collectionName --drop --file=file.json --jsonArray

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can aggregate into a document using the `$group` stage.

Comment: A document is limited to 16MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved, thanks to both [prasad_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4679320/prasad) and [Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2282634/joe).

After using the mongoimport that is shown in my question, I just aggregated using $group to get everything into one document. Though there was a problem which Joe commented, that a document is limited to 16MB. Which meant that I had to remove some data from the dataset that I wasn't using.